# Unable to install nginx on machine ubuntu 20. Error with nginx-core and other related packages

Tags: 20.04, nginx

I'm trying to install `nginx` with `sudo apt install nginx` but I keep getting the following error:

```
Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1) | nginx-full (>= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1) | nginx-light (>= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1) | nginx-extras (>= 1.18.0-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     Setting up libgeoip1:amd64 (1.6.12-6build1) ...
Setting up geoip-database (20191224-2) ...
Setting up libnginx-mod-http-geoip (1.18.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
```

I have followed other SO answers about purging and then reinstalling (example of my history of commands)

```bsh
  231  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  232  sudo apt-get update
  233  sudo apt-get purge nginx
  234  sudo apt-get install nginx nginx-core nginx-common
```

but I keep getting the same error. How can I fix this installation, thanks.

When I try to restart the `nginx` I get the following error:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Have you considered getting the output of `systemctl status nginx.service` and `journalctl -u nginx.service` to see if it gives any specific errors?  If not, then run both commands and include the output here as an edit to your question.  USUALLY this is because you've got chaotic configs in place or something didn't install right.

Comment: We would possibly understand the problem better if you would put the full, unredacted output of each command immediately after each command.  I'm 100% certain that you aren't getting the exact same output for all of these commands.  By redacting and combining these, you could be losing information.